# How do I set a bool property using conditionals from other properties?

Tags: c#, if-statement

So I have these properties and I want to set another one depending on these:

```
    public DateTime? StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? EndDate { get; set; }
    private bool _hasDateRange;
```

I want to set the `_hasDateRange` to true or false depending if StartDate and EndDate is different from null.

What I've come up with is this, but it doesn't seem to work;

```
public DateTime? StartDate { get; set; }
public DateTime? EndDate { get; set; }
private bool _hasDateRange;
public bool HasRange
    {
        get => _hasDateRange;
        set
        {
            if (this.StartDate != null && this.EndDate != null)
            {
                this._hasDateRange = true;
            }
            else
            {
                this._hasDateRange = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Use a property with a getter only. Let the getter do the check whether StartDate and EndDate have valid values. No need for a setter nor backing field here...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want a get-only property. Why would you want to be required to call a setter first to compute the value? The setter of any property should assign the value of the special variable `value` to the backing field of the property, not ignore it.

You want the return value of the property computed:

```
public bool HasRange
{
    get
    {
        if (this.StartDate != null && this.EndDate != null)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

The backing field (`_hasDateRange`) is now no longer required and can be removed.

Multiple reduction steps can be applied to the property's definition:

##### Step 1

```
public bool HasRange
{
    get
    {
        return this.StartDate != null && this.EndDate != null;
    }
}
```

##### Step 2

```
public bool HasRange
{
    get => this.StartDate != null && this.EndDate != null;
}
```

##### Step 3

```
public bool HasRange => this.StartDate != null && this.EndDate != null;
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a setter that has to be called in order to work, you can use a read only property with only a getter. In the code of the getter, check the values of the other properties and you are good to go:

```
public bool HasRange
{
    get => StartDate.HasValue && End date.HasValue;
}
```

Whenever the value of `HasRange` is requested, it is evaluated based upon the other properties so there is no chance that the values are out of sync